# Как в Gulp JS разделить выходящий поток на несколько файлов?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

В проекте есть 3 сборки фронтэнда:
1. Для лендинга
2. Для форума
3. Для основного сайта

Они используют разные скрипты и стили, но обработчик gulp должен быть один и тот же. Не хочется копировать логику выполнения три раза для каждой задачи.

## gulpfile.js

```
var gulp    = require('gulp');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var path    = require('./../../config.json');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src(path.forum.css.input)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.forum.css.output));
});
```

## config.json

```
{
    "forum": {
        "css": {
            "input": [
                "./src/Application/forum/**/*.css"
            ],
            "output": "./web/forum/css"
        }
    },
    "landing": {
        "css": {
            "input": [
                "./src/Application/landing/**/*.css"
            ],
            "output": "./web/landing/css"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно оформить задачу как отдельную функцию, выделив переменные части, вынести их в аргументы для функции. Так как конфигурационный файл у вас хорошо организован, то достаточно вынести только название раздела:

```
// @param {string} section - название раздела в конфиге ("forum", "landing", ...)
function css(section) {
    return function () {
        return gulp.src(path[section].css.input)
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path[section].css.output));
    };
}
```

Тогда задача для каждого раздела будет выглядеть так:

```
gulp.task('css:landing', css('landing'));    
gulp.task('css:forum', css('forum'));
gulp.task('css:main', css('main'));
```

Собрать их в зависимость можно дополнительной задачей:

```
gulp.task('css', ['css:landing', 'css:forum', 'css:main']);
```

Comment: Этот вариант мне понравился больше тем, что собирать файлы можно будет модульно (раздельно). В то время как merge-stream как я понял, пересобирает каждый раз для всех потоков заново, что увеличит в свою очередь время сборки при разрастании проекта.

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативный вариант - использовать пакет [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream), что позволит осуществить все в одной задаче, при этом не ломая поток выполнения Gulp.

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    // определяем разделы
    var sections = ['landing', 'forum', 'main'];

    // для каждого раздела в цикле создается поток выполнения
    var streams = sections.map(function (section) {

        // выполнение действий для каждого раздела
        return gulp.src(path[section].css.input)
            .pipe(plumber())
            .pipe(gulp.dest(path[section].css.output));
        });

    });

    // объединение потоков для Gulp
    return merge(streams);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде так тоже должно сработать:

**config.json**

```
{
    "path": {
        "input": "./src/Application",
        "output": "./web"
    }
}
```

---

**gulpfile.js**

```
...
var fs = require('fs'),
    config = require('./../../config.json');
...
var dirs = fs.readdirSync(config.path.input);
...
gulp.task('css', function () {
   dirs.forEach(function(d) {
      return gulp.src(path.join(config.path.input, d, '/**/*.css'))
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(config.path.output, d, '/css')));
   });
});
```